# writeToFile in documents directory not updating until I restart the app

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage, writetofile

I am using the documents directory of my application to cache images locally, but when I go to access them, they are not updated until I close the app and reopen.

Here is my save:

```
    var readPath = ""
    let nsDocumentDirectory = NSSearchPathDirectory.DocumentDirectory
    let nsUserDomainMask = NSSearchPathDomainMask.UserDomainMask
    if let paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(nsDocumentDirectory, nsUserDomainMask, true) {
        if paths.count > 0 {
            if let dirPath = paths[0] as? String {
                readPath = dirPath.stringByAppendingPathComponent("\(user).png")
                UIImagePNGRepresentation(imageView.image).writeToFile(readPath, atomically: true)
            }
        }
    }
```

Here is my retrieval:

```
    var readPath = ""
    let nsDocumentDirectory = NSSearchPathDirectory.DocumentDirectory
    let nsUserDomainMask = NSSearchPathDomainMask.UserDomainMask
    if let paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(nsDocumentDirectory, nsUserDomainMask, true) {
        if paths.count > 0 {
            if let dirPath = paths[0] as? String {
                readPath = dirPath.stringByAppendingPathComponent("\(user).png")

                //UIImagePNGRepresentation(imageView.image).writeToFile(readPath, atomically: true)
            }
        }
    }

    let cachedImage = UIImage(named: readPath)

    if (cachedImage != nil)
    {
        println("cached")
        self.userPictures.append(cachedImage!)

    }
```

For some reason though, it is not until I have reset the application that these resources become available.

Can anyone shed some light on why this could be?

The image that gets returned to cachedImage is an image that I had previously saved into that specific path btw

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may helps you....

```
    let fileManager = NSFileManager.defaultManager()

    var paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)[0] as! String

    var getImagePath = paths.stringByAppendingPathComponent("\(fileName).png")

    if (fileManager.fileExistsAtPath(getImagePath))
    {
        println("FILE AVAILABLE");

        //Pick Image and Use accordingly
        var imageis: UIImage = UIImage(contentsOfFile: getImagePath)!

        self.image = imageis // UIImageView Class

        let datas: NSData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(imageis)
    }
    else
    {
        println("FILE NOT AVAILABLE");

        let getImage =  UIImage(data: self.data)
        self.image = getImage
        var filePathToWrite = "\(paths)/\(fileName).png"

        var imageData: NSData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(self.image)

        fileManager.createFileAtPath(filePathToWrite, contents: imageData, attributes: nil)

    }
```

Check the Project in [Github](https://github.com/JaleelNazir/MJTableImageSwift)